# Using Boto3 to interact with amazon Aurora on RDS

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have set up a database in Amazon RDS using Amazon Aurora and would like to interact with the database using Python - the obvious choice is to use Boto.

However, their documentation is awful and does nopt cover ways in which I can interact with the databse to:

- Run queries with SQL statements
- Interact with the tables in the database
- etc

Does anyone have an links to some examples/tutorials, or know how to do these tasks?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using Amazon RDS offerings (including Aurora), you don't connect to the database via any AWS API (including Boto). Instead you would use the native client of your chosen database. In the case of Aurora, you would connect using the MySQL Command Line client. From there, you can query it just like any other MySQL database.

There's a brief section of the "Getting Started" documentation that talks about connecting to your Aurora database:

[Connecting to an Amazon Aurora DB Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html)

Comment: thank you. Excuse my naivety here, but how would I then go about creating and API to get data via queries for use in a web/mobile app? Is there a set of services or API for example?

Comment: @user3024827 - Nope. No API. You simply connect to your database just as you would if it were local. RDS is nothing more than a hosted database solution.

Comment: so does this mean it cannot be used as the database for an application? Again apologies if this is a silly question, I am very new to it!

Comment: @user3024827 - It most definitely can be used as the database for an application. I'm merely saying that you don't treat it any differently than if you were running a database server locally.

Comment: @JustinNiessner - When I threat Aurora with the native client, performance are poor comparing to same query running using Node.JS API. I just submitted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116451/how-to-improve-query-time-from-aws-aurora-rds-when-using-python-3-executed-on?noredirect=1#comment98867091_56116451) about that

Comment: I feel this answer can create more ambiguity and guiding someone looking for a way to connect to Aurora using Boto3.
There are APIs to connect to 'rds-data' using boto3 and then run queries.
This can be especially useful when trying to use secret manager instead of using username passwords directly to connect.

Comment: This answer feels really out of date. The normal way for interacting with the database in the AWS cloud from outside the cloud is via an SDK (API). Connecting like the on-prem way of thinking might be workable if the rest of the application is contained within the same VPC and is using common compute platforms (EC2 - Lambda) in AWS.

Answer (score 15):

Here are a couple examples:

**INSERT example:**

```
import boto3

sql = """
        INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE
        (
            your_column_name_1
            ,your_column_name_2
            ,your_column_name_3)
        VALUES(
            :your_param_1_name
            ,:your_param_2_name)
            ,:your_param_3_name
        """

param1 = {'name':'your_param_1_name', 'value':{'longValue': 5}}
param2 = {'name':'your_param_2_name', 'value':{'longValue': 63}}
param3 = {'name':'your_param_3_name', 'value':{'stringValue': 'para bailar la bamba'}}

param_set = [param1, param2, param3]

db_clust_arn = 'your_db_cluster_arn_here'

db_secret_arn = 'your_db_secret_arn_here'

rds_data = boto3.client('rds-data')

response = rds_data.execute_statement(
    resourceArn = db_clust_arn, 
    secretArn = db_secret_arn, 
    database = 'your_database_name_here', 
    sql = sql,
    parameters = param_set)

print(str(response))
```

**READ example:**

```
import boto3

rds_data = boto3.client('rds-data')

db_clust_arn = 'your_db_cluster_arn_here'

db_secret_arn = 'your_db_secret_arn_here'


employee_id = 35853

get_vacation_days_sql = f"""
    select vacation_days_remaining
    from employees_tbl
    where employee_id = {employee_id}    
        """


response1 = rds_data.execute_statement(
        resourceArn = db_clust_arn, 
        secretArn = db_secret_arn, 
        database = 'your_database_name_here', 
        sql = get_vacation_days_sql)

#recs is a list (of rows returned from Db)
recs = response1['records']

print(f"recs === {recs}")
#recs === [[{'longValue': 57}]]

#single_row is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a 
#column from that single row
for single_row in recs:
    print(f"single_row === {single_row}")
    #single_row === [{'longValue': 57}]
    
    #one_dict is a dictionary with one key value pair
    #where the key is the data type of the column and the 
    #value is the value of the column
    #each additional column is another dictionary
    for single_column_dict in single_row:
        print(f"one_dict === {single_column_dict}")
        # one_dict === {'longValue': 57}

        vacation_days_remaining = single_column_dict['longValue']
        
        print(f'vacation days remaining === {vacation_days_remaining}')
```

Source Link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.calling.python

Comment: there is no rds-data client in Boto3 when you run in on Glue

Comment: In the READ example, you should use the params like in the other example instead of the f-string, to avoid potential sql injection.

Comment: This is only applicable if you are running Aurora Serverless and have enabled the Data API.

Comment: Does this work for Aurora Serverless V2, which apparently doesn't have the Data API?