# How to improve query time from AWS Aurora (RDS) when using Python 3 executed on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pymysql, amazon-aurora

I'm using Python 3 with `pymysql` package to query raw data from `AWS Aurora` while executing from an EC2 with Amazon Linux. And I'd like to improve the performance significantly.

So far, I managed to get the job done but it takes 150 seconds to get the results of 2.3 million rows back, using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host, user=user,port=port,
                       passwd=password, db=dbname)

myQuery = '''
    SELECT * FROM fEvents f  
    Left Join fParams fp  
    on f.id = fp.id 
    WHERE f.DateTime BETWEEN '2019-01-24' and '2019-02-28' 
    '''

df = pd.read_sql(myQuery, con=conn)
```

When we tried executing the same query from the same EC2 using `node.js` we got an object with the 2.3 million results within **only 20 seconds!**
Since the rest of the code is in Python 3, I'm struggling to improve the performance of my Python API.

I'll appreciate any suggestions or explanations please.

Comment: `read_sql` is transforming the query results into a Pandas `Dataframe`. Are you doing something similar with the None version, or just executing the query?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the fetching and conversion to pandas data frame is taking just 10 seconds out of the 150 seconds. I was able to break that apart using the `SQLAlchemy` engine. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If you're executing the same query _and retrieving all of the records_ in both cases, then the difference is going to be in how the database driver manages the results. The `pymysql` driver claims to be pure Python, and is transforming the raw data stream into Python objects. I don't know what you're using for Node, but it's entirely possible that it's using a much more performant way to manage the results. It's possible that another library would be faster, but I can't give you any recommendations.

Comment: @guest - thanks, I tend to agree with you on that assumption. a good recommendation on a different approach will be nice.