# How to connect to RDS aurora serverless MYSQL private DB using Boto3?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I tried searching ways to connect to **RDS aurora serverless MYSQL private db** found a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468372/using-boto3-to-interact-with-amazon-aurora-on-rds#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20a%20couple%20examples), but it is asking secret arn of the DB, unable to find that one out
can anyone help me with the way to generate secret ARN or a way to connect to  **RDS aurora serverless MYSQL private db**
i am able to fetch all remaining details for the option mentioned in the above link,
steps i am following:

1. created **RDS aurora serverless MYSQL private db**
2. connected a ec2 instance
3. generating python script to connect to rds
   if you suggest any alternative, that is also fine,
   TIA

Comment: "secret ARN" what is that? I think you must be confusing something. Please update the question and provide exact details of what you want to do and any errors you are getting.

Comment: it is mentioned in the hyper link i had provided above marcin, please check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468372/using-boto3-to-interact-with-amazon-aurora-on-rds#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20a%20couple%20examples) once, also thanks for your concern, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, the detailed explanation is there in [amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html#:%7E:text=import%20mysql.connector). Add an IAM role for your EC2 instance and try giving your db password in the passwd field of above mentioned code. feel free to contact if needed, apologies for the poor answer structure(a newbie trying to help community) :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).