# How do I create an aws rds aurora database with some tables with python aws cdk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

I want to create an AWS stack with the python aws-cdk library.

The requirements are as such: There must exist an aurora3 mysql database and it needs to have 2 tables (as a reduced example, lets say `table1` needs to have 2 fields: `id` of integer type and `name` of string type, and `table2` needs to have `table1_id` of integer which is a foreign key to table1, and a `data` field of string type

I have found some tutorials online on how to do this through the console, but I need to do it from within code, and not manually through the console, and the documentation seems lacking for this

Comment: You would need to spin up the database which is the infrastructure using CDK then as a second unrelated step execute SQL to create the tables etc. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35468443/839338

Comment: @Dan-Dev Could you provide some code or at least some concrete examples?

Comment: You can build [Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) (even in the same stack) that can then be invoked to interact with the database.  But it would be easier to put database initialization into the application that already interacts with the database and can "own" the schema.

Answer (score 1):

The CDK code looks like this, call it from your app.py as you would normally

```
from aws_cdk import Stack, aws_rds, aws_ec2, triggers, aws_lambda, aws_secretsmanager, Duration
from constructs import Construct


class CdkRdsStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(
            self, "my_vpc", ip_addresses=aws_ec2.IpAddresses.cidr("10.0.0.0/16")
        )
        selection = vpc.select_subnets(
            subnet_type=aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
        )

        my_security_group = aws_ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "SecurityGroup",
            vpc=vpc,
            description="Allow RDS access",
            allow_all_outbound=True,
            disable_inline_rules=True
        )
        my_security_group.add_ingress_rule(
            aws_ec2.Peer.security_group_id(my_security_group.security_group_id),
            aws_ec2.Port.tcp(3306))

        db = aws_rds.DatabaseCluster(
            self,
            "my_database",
            engine=aws_rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.aurora_mysql(
                version=aws_rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_3_05_1
            ),
            credentials=aws_rds.Credentials.from_generated_secret(
                username="database_cluster_creds",
                secret_name="database_cluster_creds",
            ),
            writer=aws_rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned(
                "writer", publicly_accessible=False
            ),
            readers=[
                aws_rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned("reader1", promotion_tier=1),
                aws_rds.ClusterInstance.serverless_v2("reader2"),
            ],
            vpc_subnets=aws_ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
            ),
            vpc=vpc,
            default_database_name="database_cluster",
            security_groups=[my_security_group],

        )
        database_cluster_creds = aws_secretsmanager.Secret.from_secret_name_v2(
            self,
            "database_cluster_creds",
            secret_name="database_cluster_creds"
        )

        lambda_fn = aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            "MyFunction",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_11,
            handler="lambda_function.handler",
            code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda/lambda_function.zip"),
            vpc=vpc,
            vpc_subnets=aws_ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
            ),
            timeout=Duration.seconds(40),
            security_groups=[my_security_group]
        )

        database_cluster_creds.grant_read(lambda_fn.role)

        triggers.Trigger(
            self,
            "MyTrigger",
            handler=lambda_fn,
            execute_after=[db],
            # execute_on_handler_change=False,
        )
```

The CDK  creates a trigger for a lambda the lambda updates the database using boto3.  It is automatically triggered on every build but you can change this if you want

The lambda code needs packaging in a zip file with a package, from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-lambda-tutorial.html#vpc-rds-update-function (the lambda code is not the same as we use here)

> To include the PyMySQL dependency with your function code, create a
> .zip deployment package. The following commands work for Linux, macOS,
> or Unix: To create a .zip deployment package
>
> Save the example code as a file named lambda_function.py.
>
> In the same directory in which you created your lambda_function.py file, create a new directory named package and install the PyMySQL library.
>
> ```
>  mkdir package
>  pip install --target package pymysql
> ```
>
> Create a zip file containing your application code and the PyMySQL
> library. In Linux or MacOS, run the following CLI commands. In
> Windows, use your preferred zip tool to create the lambda_function.zip
> file. Your lambda_function.py source code file and the folders
> containing your dependencies must be installed at the root of the .zip
> file.
>
> ```
> cd package
> zip -r ../lambda_function.zip .
> cd ..
> zip lambda_function.zip lambda_function.py
> ```

Otherwise, google how to make a lambda layer using CDK and a zip file created on an EC2

The code looks like this it uses a credential CDK puts in AWS secrets manager:

```
import json
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def get_secret():
    secret_name = "database_cluster_creds"
    region_name = "eu-west-2"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as ex:
        raise ex

    return json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])


try:
    secrets = get_secret()
    conn = pymysql.connect(
        host=secrets.get("host"),
        user=secrets.get("username"),
        passwd=secrets.get("password"),
        db=secrets.get("dbname"),
        connect_timeout=5
    )
except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit(1)

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS for MySQL instance succeeded")


def handler(_, __):
    """
    This function creates a new RDS database table and writes records to it
    """

    cust_id = 334
    name = "Dummy Name"

    item_count = 0
    sql_string = f"insert into Customer (CustID, Name) values({cust_id}, '{name}')"

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(
            "create table if not exists Customer ( CustID  int NOT NULL, Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CustID))")
        cur.execute(sql_string)
        conn.commit()
        cur.execute("select * from Customer")
        logger.info("The following items have been added to the database:")
        for row in cur:
            item_count += 1
            logger.info(row)
    conn.commit()

    return f"Added {item_count} items to RDS for MySQL table"
```

The lambda logs to CloudWatch:

```
2024-02-10T04:22:49.079+00:00
[INFO]  2024-02-10T04:22:49.079Z    bf5039c9-1ed3-46b4-bc07-aad8337b2e06    The following items have been added to the database:
2024-02-10T04:22:49.079+00:00
[INFO]  2024-02-10T04:22:49.079Z    bf5039c9-1ed3-46b4-bc07-aad8337b2e06    (334, 'Dummy Name')
```

The AWS region in the lambda may be different to yours

You will have to write the SQL as you want it

Comment: Don't create a security group, don't place your lambda in the DB's security group (don't pass security groups to either). Instead, simply do `db.connections.allow_default_port_from(lambda_fn)`

Comment: @gshpychka Yeah, that works too with less CDK code but the Cfn looks very similar. I was just trying to throw some rough code together as the OP asked for examples